# For arbitrary $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ prove $(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)\ge8abc$

Tags: inequality

For arbitrary a,b,c prove $(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)\ge8abc$

I originaly expanded the left hand side and got
$a^2b^2c^2+a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2+a^2+b^2+c^2+1-8abc\ge0$

any suggestions from here would be helpful

Comment: Try to read this "http://www.aam.org.in/site/st_material/14.pdf" in order to improve your knowledge about inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $AM \ge GM$:
$$(a^2b^2c^2+a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2+a^2+b^2+c^2+1)/8 \ge (a^8b^8c^8)^{1/8} = |abc| \ge abc$$

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:** Using the AM-GM inequality

$$1 + a^2 \ge 2a$$

Comment: It's equivalent to $(a-1)^2\ge 0$, which is true for all $a\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @user236182 Yeah, that's another way to put it.